# Complex SharePoint Calendar Validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, validation, column-validation

=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY([Start Time]),FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

Assuming [Start Time] at 12:30, 1:15 or 1:30 PM

```
=AND(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY([Start Time]),FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),IF(OR(TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="12:30",TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="13:15",TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="13:30"),TRUE,FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! Do you have any ideas on how to get the 15 min. limit to work?

Comment: That's means, [End Time] - [Start Time] =15 minutes, right? Yes, that can be done. I will try later today.